# Why jQuery's triggerHandler() doesn't prevent inline events?

Tags: javascript, jquery, eventtrigger

I've made this test code for the question: https://jsfiddle.net/5phqm/1/

As far as I understand, if jQuery's `triggerHandler()` prevents default browser behavior, then native JavaScript events will not be triggered and handled (and it's true for `addEventListener()` in my code), but inline event, added through tag's attribute `onclick=""` will be triggered anyway! Why it happens? Am I misunderstanding something about events triggering in browser?

Comment: For what it's worth I always think of this as following the CSS rules pattern of behaviour: the in-line code overrides the code found in the `head` which in turn overrides the code found in an external script. You could simply `removeAttr('onclick')`.

Comment: This is not a direct answer but at the jQuery website they state they do not spend effort on issues with inline event handlers: http://docs.jquery.com/Won't_Fix#Inline_Event_Handlers. I'd be interested to know why your code behaves as it does, but I don't think there will be a fix for it (in case you find it a bug).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can be confirmed that inline handlers are run because it is [explicitly coded](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/event.js#L342):

```
handle = ontype && cur[ ontype ];
if ( handle && jQuery.acceptData( cur ) && handle.apply( cur, data ) === false ) {
    event.preventDefault();
}
```

where `ontype` is in this case `"onclick"`. So it is fetching the `onclick` property of the element and then executing it. This piece of code is always called, regardless of `.trigger`/`.triggerHandler`.

Native actions however, like `elem.click()`, are only executed [inside an `if` block](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/event.js#L371):

```
if ( !onlyHandlers && !event.isDefaultPrevented() ) {
    // ...
    elem[ type ]();
```

where `onlyHandlers` is `true` for `triggerHandle` and `false` for `.trigger`, and therefore `triggerHandler` does not execute e.g. `elem.click()` (whereas `.trigger` does). As such, the native action is prevented.

So inline handlers and native actions are separate things and are also handled separately. Only native actions are prevented by `.triggerHandler`.

Answer (score 0):

I think (but it's a guess, i gave a brief look at jQuery source code and this might be totally wrong) that jQuery retrieves the events attached to elements in jQuery.trigger.event by calling something like

```
   $(elem).data("events");
```

and then decides if to fire/stop them. Inline events can't be collected this way and so they can't be stopped.